# How to return lambda that contains other lambdas?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have map of values. I need to cast Any for some type and then invoke function `send()`

```
 fun mapToMessage(map: Map<String, Any>?): (Meesage.() -> Unit)? {
        if (map.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            return null
        }

        map.forEach { (key, value) ->
              when (value) {
                is String -> return { send(key, value) }
                is Int -> return { send(key, value)}
            }
        }
    }
```

Function `mapToMessage()` should return lambda like:

```
{
   send(key1, value1)
   send(key2, value2)
}
```

but right now return only one Unit.
How I can create lambda which contains all units from map?

Comment: Returning this as a lambda is making this much more complicated.  Why return a lambda, when you can create a lambda that calls the normal method `mapToMessage(message, map)`?

Comment: Another core function takes lambda as a parameter

Comment: What do you mean it returns only one Unit? Why does that matter? Unit is just what any function returns if it has nothing useful to return.

Comment: @Wafi_ck: Then create the lambda where you call that method.  For example, instead of calling `mapToMessage(map)` to return a lambda, write `{message -> mapToMessage(message, map)}` so it can e.g. be inlined, or so `mapToMessage` is much easier to write and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you have is to return a lambda which iterates through the `Map` and invokes the functions:

```
fun mapToMessage(map: Map<String, Any>?): (Meesage.() -> Unit)? {
    if (map.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        return null
    }

    return {
        map.forEach { (key, value) ->
            when (value) {
                is String -> send(key, value)
                is Int -> send(key, value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But it return lambda with only one Unit

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "lambda with only one Unit" and what you expect instead?

Comment: Lambda that contains all of created send() functions.

Comment: Ohh, that's weird. I had to restart my IDE and now it works as expected. Last time, those changes didn't apply to my app. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to return a lambda that *contains* all those other lambdas, and runs them all when invoked?

```
val lambdas = map.mapNotNull { (key, value) ->
    when (value) {
        is String -> { send(key, value) }
        is Int -> { send(key, value)}
        else -> null
    }
}

return { lambdas.forEach { it.invoke() } }
```

Calling them *Units* is a little confusing. `Unit` is a kind of "nothing" return value - the type your function returns is `Meesage.() -> Unit`, which is a function that *returns no value*. There's no concept of "how many there are" - that would be a value, so it wouldn't be `Unit`

Comment: I want to return a lambda that contains all those other lambdas and pass it to another function. When I use your code and at the end type:  return  { lambdas }, IDE shows "this expression is unused"